# NeoVim: Following the instructions in ":h clipboard-wsl" not work? It shows "no provider" but also "ok" in ":checkhealth"?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, wsl

I am using neovim on archlinux/WSL2, and try to communicate with the Windows clipboard in neovim.

Following the instructions in `:h clipboard-wsl`, I filled in `init.lua` with code:

```lua
vim.g.clipboard = {
 name = 'WslClipboard',
 copy = {
 ["+"] = 'clip.exe',
 ["*"] = 'clip.exe',
 },
 paste = {
 ["+"] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
 ["*"] = 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
},
 cache_enabled = 0,
 }
```

But when I try to yank using `"+y`, I get "Clipboard: No Provider". However running `:checkhealth`, I get:

```
Clipboard (optional)
   - OK Clipboard tool found: WslClipboard
```

If I run `echo "hello world" | clip.exe` in the terminal, all work fine: I can paste "hello world" in windows side. And so is the `powershell.exe ...` command.

After I yank something, I can't find the content in '+' register or '*' register, they are just missing in the result of `:reg`. So I'm inclined to think the clipboard function is not trigerred, then I tried to install `xclip`, and luckily the problem is solved.

Comment: Are you using Vim or Neovim? Which is the distribution you are using?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It seems to work fine for me. Are the `clip.exe` and `powershell.exe` command running smooth in WSL?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I'm using neovim on archlinux@WSL2, and the `clip.exe` and `powershell.exe` both work fine in the terminal. It would be nice if you can tell me how to debug and what to look into.

Comment: Something weird is going on.  "Clipboard: No Provider" and "Clipboard tool found" are total contradictions.  I'm inclined to think you backed into a corner case (a bug that appears rarely).  Try reinstalling neovim.  Try a newer version; try an older version.  Try another wsl distribution.  Basically try to reproduce this issue in multiple environments, and don't do any copy-pasting.  This is to ensure that the bug is reproducible and isn't contingent on some of your config (that you haven't posted here because it's seemingly irrelevant).

Comment: Could you tell us what is the result of: `:echo g:clipboard`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It's ``{'paste': {'*': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))', '+': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))'}, 'cache_enabled': 0, 'name': 'WslClipboard', 'copy': {'*': 'clip.exe', '+': 'clip.exe'}}``

Comment: I have the same. I use nvim 0.6.1 on wsl. What is your version of nvim?

Answer (score 1):

Well I fix the problem by simply installing `xclip`. I don't know why, and I used to think that is unneeded because I'm not going to use the clipboard in X11 but the one in Windows.

Comment: Did you also changed the neovim configuration?

Comment: I have `xclip` but because I'm in console mode `xclip` complains about `Error: Can't open display: (null)`.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt No, I didn't change any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `win32yank` its much faster than using `powershell` and `xclip`.

Download the `win32yank` binary here https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank/releases then copy it to `/usr/local/bin` dont forget, should be `chmod +x win32yank.exe`.

After that add this to your neovim config.

```lua
    vim.g.clipboard = {
        name = "win32yank-wsl",
        copy = {
            ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf",
            ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf",
        },
        paste = {
            ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -o --lf",
            ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -o --lf",
        },
        cache_enabled = true,
    }
```